# How is inner conflict presented in the poem "Tissue"?

Tags: poetry, symbolism, imtiaz-dharker

We haven't studied this poem in class due to the COVID-19 outbreak and schools shutting down, but we have made annotations for the poem. However nothing about conflict came up.

Have you got any ideas how inner conflict is shown in Imtiaz Dharker's poem [Tissue](https://genius.com/Imtiaz-dharker-tissue-annotated)?